# EvtID:10060:Cannot connect to....A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlclient, azure-sql-server

I am try to connect `Azure Cloud Sql Database` from my local machine through `SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2017/18`.In Server Firewall Rule added client IP,but Not getting connected and throwing error as below.

> ===================================
>
> Cannot connect to integtenantelasticsql.database.windows.net.
>
> ===================================
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (.Net
> SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10060&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Error Number: 10060 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
> DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
> sqlAuthProviderManager)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
> ci, IServerType server)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
>
> ===================================
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond

Also performed the following Operations:

-Network reset

-IPV4 and IPV6 DNS server address update.

-SQL Server Configuration Manager IPV4 TCP enable disable

-SQL Server services stop, start.

-System windows 10 64bit up to date.

-Network driver uninstall installation.

-Telnet

> Telnet cmd: telnet integtenantelasticsql.database.windows.net. 443
> working.

-C# sql client:

I have tried sample console app using c# Sql client, but getting the same issue.

Not getting what is the issue? Help is very much appreciate.

Could you please suggest me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [To access Azure SQL Database from your local computer, ensure that the firewall on your network and local computer allow outgoing communication on TCP port `1433`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure)

Comment: see your firewall and define ports in fire wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with TCP port `1433` not there in my system firewall Inbound setting.

So have did the following steps

-Enabling protocols for port 1433

-Create a Firewall exception

-And Apply to the Database Engine Instance Service

for more details reference link [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-error-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/).

After follow the same reference link problem got solved.